# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} \binom{n}{k}$ using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

How do I compute $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} \binom{n}{k}$ using generating functions? I'm trying to make a generalization for a competition math problem, namely [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2017_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_7).

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$. Our problem is the special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) with $m=2n,\,r=n$, so the answer is $\binom{3n}{n}$. [This algebraic proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Algebraic_proof) uses coefficients in generating functions - to be precise, polynomials, i.e. generating functions with only finitely many nonzero coefficients. In particular, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{3n}{n}$ follows from evaluating the $x^n$ coefficient in $(1+x)^{2n}(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{3n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the coefficient extractor thingy, Eg.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{k} = [x^0]: \frac{(1+x)^{2n}}{x^k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}   \binom{2n}{k} &=& [x^0]: \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(1+x)^{2n}}{x^k} \\  
&=& [x^0] :  (1+x)^{2n} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^n  \\  
&=& [x^n] :  (1+x)^{3n} = \color{red}{\binom{3n}{n}}.
\end{eqnarray*}